# How to force Visual Studio to use the TFS source control provider and not GIT provider

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

EDIT:
this is a [known issues](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/180080/cannot-disable-git-vs2017-1553.html) and will not be "fixed"

The question then is how do I configure git to name the .git folder something else for this one repo.

## I don't want to use the GIT_DIR environment variable as that would be a system wide.

We are evaluating Azure DevOps (using git) and I'd like to use an existing project which is currently under on-prem TFS.

I'm perfectly comfortable using git from the cli, but VS2017 automatically defaults to using the Git source control provider. If I change it back to TFS, it warns me and closes the solution. when I re-open it, I'm back to the GIT source control provider.

Short of uninstalling the git source control provider, are there any other options?

I've surmised that if VS sees a folder, even an empty one, named .git it uses the GIT provider.
Is it possible to configure git to use a different folder in place of .git?

Comment: So what is unclear in your question is are you using git in TFS for your source control? If you are then this is expected behavior, now if your solution is in TFVC it shouldn't even mention Git.  So which version control system is your project stored in? Git or TFVC?

Answer (score 0):

You would try the following steps:

1. Make sure you are connected to TFS/Azure DevOps in VS.
2. Make sure your source control is selected as VSTFS plugin from Tools->Options->Source Control.
3. Now try to Add Solution to Source Control, it will ask where you need to add the solution in your TFS instance.